# NameError at /accounts/regist_save/

Tags: python, django

I got a error,
NameError at /accounts/regist_save/
global name 'Token' is not defined.
I think my app do not have necessary things,so
I add `from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token` into models.py and `rest_framework.authtoken` into settings.py.
But in that time,there are many error in my console,so I deleted them.
So,what should I do to fix this error?

I wrote in views.py,

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/profile.html', context)


def regist(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/regist.html', context)


@require_POST
def regist_save(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('registration/accounts/profile.html', context)


    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/regist.html', context)
```

in models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.conf import settings
# from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

# Create your models here.
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):

    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

in urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', login,
        {'template_name': 'registration/accounts/login.html'},
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^regist/$', views.regist,name='regist' ),
    url(r'^regist_save/$', views.regist_save, name='regist_save'),
]
```

In console,it shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 40, in inner
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Desktop/XXX/accounts/views.py", line 74, in regist_save
    user = form.save()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 116, in save
    user.save()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 80, in save
    super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 796, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 833, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 191, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/Users/Desktop/XXX/UserToken/models.py", line 12, in create_auth_token
    Token.objects.create(user=instance)
NameError: global name 'Token' is not defined
[31/Jan/2017 02:51:19] "POST /accounts/regist_save/ HTTP/1.1" 500 95382
```

Comment: what errors do you get when you do use `from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token` ?  That is the error(s) you probably want help with since a NameError is simply "there isn't anything defined with that name"

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen thx,I added my edit.

Comment: I asked about the error that you get when you do import `Token` the only possible fix for a `NameError` is "define that name / import the thing with that name"